# Security Level for WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, activex, webbrowser-control, hta

I am trying to migrate an **.hta** application to a C# executable. Of course, since it's an **.hta** the code is all **HTML** and **Jscript**, with calls to local **ActiveX** objects.

I created a **C#** executable project and am just using the **WebBrowser** control to display the **HTML** content. Simply renamed the **.hta** to an **.html** and took out the HTA declarations.

Everything works great, except that when I make calls to the **ActiveX** objects, I get a security popup warning of running an **ActiveX** control on the page.

I understand why this is happening since the WebBrowser control is essentially IE and uses the Internet Options security settings, but is there any way to get the WebBrowser control to bypass security popups, or a way to register the executable or DLLs as being trusted without having to change settings in Internet Options? Even a way to do on a deployment package would work as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WebBrowser` is an instance of Internet Explorer, and inherits security settings from IE.

One way could be to change the security settings defined in IE.

The other way could be to add a [Custom Security Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537182%28VS.85%29.aspx) by implementing [`IInternetSecurityManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface.

> The WebBrowser Control or MSHTML hosts could create a security manager (by implementing the IInternetSecurityManager  interface) that handles the URL actions and policies that are important to the host. Other URL actions and policies would be passed to the default security manager so it could handle them appropriately. The IInternetSecurityMgrSite  interface would be used to handle Windows-related information from the component so that the customized security manager could handle any user interface it required. -

Comment: Thanks KMan, the Custom Security Manager may be just what I need. I will have to look into it further, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That link is good, but it doesn't really tell me how to access IInternetSecurityManager in C#.  Can you please give a little more detail?