# Override internet explorer security settings using custom WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I am currently working on a solution to submit a form on a web page.  The issue is my solution works fine locally but fails server side.  I'm convinced it's the elevated internet explorer security settings that cause the problem.  Consequently I am trying to write my own web browser control that provides a backdoor to the server's settings.  I've used the following as a reference: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11331098/. My problem is that when I compare the logs in my application to the ones server side the ProcessUrlAction method receives the following URL server side  res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm (not the web page I am trying to access) while all the other parameters going into the methods seem identical.  I've toggled the zone values in MapURLToZone with no success. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jberg

Comment: Have you looked at this question? The answer might be applicable to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577386/security-level-for-webbrowser-control

Comment: Yes I've looked at it. It's a little high level but the link in the original post performs the suggestion to the best of my knowledge and I'm still stuck on the navigation canceled redirect. Thanks though.

Comment: page level security settings do not apply when the navigation is cancelled. Try capture BeforeNavigate2 and check what is on the call stack when it navigates to the cancellation page.

Comment: Thanks Sheng.  I've had a look but the stack trace isn't to transparent.  I'll take a closer look at this lead.  Perhaps it has something to do with unsafe code.